# Cutting grass of vacant house next to me

Tags: ohio, civil-legal-system

Am I able to send the city a bill for cutting the grass of the vacant house next to me? It's been condemned and was supposed to be torn down last June. I can't let the grass get too high because it attracts rodents and all sorts of things and being in the city our houses are close together so I don't want those things coming into my house. I've been mowing the grass now for the past 3 years and I was told that I could send the city a bill for the mowing. Is this true? (Akron, Ohio)

Comment: Who told you that you could bill the city? was it a city employee?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not. It is your choice to cut the grass, not the city's.

Comment: ... also, the OP is trespassing

Comment: ...an action he will absolutely never be charged for.